# Using lightning:messageChannel within lightning:backgroundUtilityItem

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to use `lightning:messageChannel` within a `lightning:backgroundUtilityItem`.

This works as expected when I use `lightnting:utilityItem` and set it to start automatically, but when I change to a `lightning:backgroundUtilitytItem`, the component seems to not be able to receive messages through the `lightning:messageChannel`.

I think maybe `lightning:backgroundUtilityItem` is designed specifically with `aura:handler` in mind, so `lightning:messageChannel`'s usage of `onMessage` is incompatible, but I cannot find any information on this interaction.

Is it possible to subscribe to a message channel within a background utility item aura component?

Answer (score 1):

The Aura Components Developer Guide states [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/message_channel_considerations.htm?search_text=message), that this is a limitation:

> Lightning message service only supports Aura components that render. You can’t use lightning:messageChannel in an Aura component that uses the background utility item interface.

I haven't found any written limitations in the Lightning Web Components Developer Guide, though. Maybe worth to try LWC.